# Displaying numbers raised to the power of (as superscript)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Could anyone please let me know how I can display numbers like 100 to 10², with base 10 raised to the power of "n". The base-10 numbers are dynamic, so I cannot rely on the ASCII coding.

This is for a C# based WPF application.

Comment: Please post your code that doesn't work and explain what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Superscript` value on the `Run.BaselineAlignment` property:

[image]

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14">
    <Run Text="25" /><Run Text="2" FontSize="8" BaselineAlignment="Superscript" />
</TextBlock>
```

You can also data bind to the `Run.Text` property if you prefer:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="14">
    <Run Text="{Binding Number}" /><Run Text="{Binding Power}" FontSize="8" 
        BaselineAlignment="Superscript" />
</TextBlock>
```

Also using this method, you can set the various properties individually on the number and the power, so you can get the exact look that you want.